# How to Set BIOS serialnumber with WMIC command

Tags: command-line, bios, wmic

I have a need to change the serial number of windows device.
I am able to get the serial number using

```
wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Is there a way I can change the serialNumber using some set command.

Comment: No, it's not possible to change the serial number of a Windows device using the wmic command or any other means. The serial number, also known as the "service tag" or "system identifier," is a unique identifier assigned to the device by the manufacturer. Attempting to change the serial number would likely result in the system becoming inoperable and could void the device's warranty. It's important to use the correct serial number when seeking technical support or warranty coverage.

Comment: Thank you, I had some automation, where I am creating multiple VMs(TestDevices, which I will manage from my server) using same template, hence all devices get same serial number and not finding a way to differentiate those device on my server. So wanted to change the serial number.